# Can I create a full text index across collections?

Tags: arangodb

In my application, I have many kinds of collections with common text fields.  I'd like to be able to full text search over some or all collections. for example: Find me all ids from all collections where the name field starts with rain.

Answer (score 0):

With ArangoDB 3.4 we introduced [ArangoSearch with the views concept](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Views/ArangoSearch/).

Views are able to span muliple collections. [Read more about their capabilities in the ArangoDB Blog](https://www.arangodb.com/2018/12/arangodb-3-4-full-text-search-geojson/)